# Positioning a button at the bottom of a "absolute" <div>

Tags: html, css

I know to position a button at the bottom of div is to set the button "absolute" and place at a "relative" div.

However, I am using "hidden visibility" attr in a form, I need to set the div to absolute.
My question is how to set a button in a absolute div?

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/khongming/Aa7Ur/

```
.abc{
   width: 300px;
   height: 180px;
   background-color: #ff6700;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}
.page{
   visibility: hidden;
   position:absolute;
}

.continue {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Set its `top: 100%` and give it a negative top margin: `margin-top: -100px` (where 100px is the height + spacing needed for your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to .page css:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

If you add a 1px border to .page and to .abc (without adding the above) you'll see you're not filling the area of .abc with your .page, so positioning "to the bottom" is to the bottom of .page, but *not* to the bottom of .abc. By setting the dimensions as above , page fills the (relative) parent div .abc you're then positioning from the same dimensions, and so your placement is correct.

Comment: Thank @Skrivener for the explanation, it really clear every single doubt of mine. 
Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `width:100%` and `height:100%` in the `.page` class seems to do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/Aa7Ur/1/